# Откуда шлют запрос из file_get_contents[PHP]

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Вообщем, сайт example.ru шлёт запрос на мой сайт site.ru/privet.php через file_get_contents, и мне нужно сделать проверку или мне отправил запрос example.ru или какой то другой.(если другой - то не пускать). Видел у одного человека такое было. Возможно реализовать?

Comment: Вопрос не очень ясный, но вряд ли вы можете узнать что-то большее, чем IP адрес

Comment: Проверять какой сайт отправил ко мне запрос, не выйдет?

Comment: Ну а как Вы собираетесь выяснять, какой сайт отправил запрос? В PHP этого не предусмотрено, как, собственно, и везде. Вы можете выяснить IP адрес сайта и заблокировать доступ по этому IP, но не более.